# What's the difference between the provider level role and iamRoleStatements in a serverless template?

Tags: serverless-framework

These are [two properties](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml/) you can set in a template and I am curious how they differ and which one I should use.

The definitions don't make it clear:

`role: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXX:role/role # Overwrite the default IAM role which is used for all functions`

`iamRoleStatements: # IAM role statements so that services can be accessed in the AWS account`

Can someone explain how they differ along with use cases for both?

I'm not sure if I should just make a new provider level role with all resources the application needs and assign the `role` paramater to it, or if I should just keep the default role serverless makes, and add my own policies to the `iamRoleStatements`

Answer (score 4):

`iamRoleStatements` is designed to contain the most common permissions needed for this service. For example, you have an API gateway and a bunch of lambda functions that all use DynamoDB to store the transactional data. Almost all the lambda functions need to have permission to query DynamoDB, so `iamRoleStatements` should be configured like this.

```
provider:
  name: aws
  ...
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:DescribeTable
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
      Resource:
        - <DynamoDB table and indices arns>
```

All the lambdas will get the same `iamRoleStatements` written above. Now, say if you have a special lambda function that needs *completely* different permission sets. You can craft a role in the console, and use the `role` option to overwrite the default role which contains `iamRoleStatements`.

Comment: I should have been clearer in my question, the `role` property I'm referring to is the provider level role, not the function role. When would you use the provider level role?